# Resuming Android app after screen on&off throws IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.forms, illegalstateexception

I've a `FormsAppCompatActivity` and it is crashing every time I turn on my screen while the app is active.
These are the steps I undertake:
- Start debugging -> app shows nicely
- Turn off screen -> app still attached to debugger
- Turn on screen -> app crashes after setting the MainPage property of the Application

I have a timeout that after 30s of idleness, the app should call the `Logout()` method and return to the login page.
When I suspend the app by pressing the home button, this code still works, when I resume the app without turning screen on&off.
I already tried setting a delay in the `OnResume` like here: [App resuming results in crash with FormsAppCompatActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35892598)
It has something to do with `Fragments` and `Transactions` being commited after state loss, but I don't know how to fix it.

The exception being thrown is `Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`

In MyApp.cs:

```
    public MyApp ()
    {
        Start(message: string.Empty);
    }

    private void Start(string message) {
        var mainPage = GetMainPage();
        MainPage = mainPage; //<-- this crashes

        userService.LoggedOut += (sender, e) => {
            ThreadPool.Start(() => {
                Start (e.Message);
            }, ThreadPoolType.Ui);
        };
    }

    protected override void OnSleep ()
    {
        base.OnSleep ();
        sleepDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    protected override void OnResume () {
        base.OnResume();
        var delta = DateTime.Now - sleepDateTime;
        if (delta.TotalSeconds > SECONDS_FOR_TIMEOUT) {
            userService.Logout();
        }
    }
```

Comment: These are links to solution in Android (java code). I hope they may be useful to you or give you an insight at least:

Solution 1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575921/illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-wit

Solution 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177781/java-lang-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstanc

Solution 3: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have any (easy) control over `Fragments` and `Transactions` in Xamarin Forms.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Hopefully someone can answer this soon!